# Regex - Special alpha characters? - Python

Tags: python, regex, ascii

I have a list of simple names such as `Márquez`,

because of the `á` `(?< name >[a-zA-Z]+)` doesn't seem to be working!

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you could use

```
\w+
```

with the unicode flag. I assume there's no risk of having digits or underscore in your names.

```
>>> re.findall('\w+', 'Márquez', re.U)
['Márquez']
```

You also seem to be missing `P` after the question mark: `(?P< name >[a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: This doesn't look good for Python < 3.0 – I don't like the idea of using the UNICODE option with regular (non-unicode) strings.

Comment: In Python 2.x str type and "xxxx" literal contains just a string of bytes. This bytes may be some characters in a specific encoding, but without encoding information these are just bytes. 'Márquez' is: (77, 195, 161, 114, 113, 117, 101, 122) (8 bytes) if your encoding is 'utf-8' or (77, 225, 114, 113, 117, 101, 122) (7 bytes)  if the encoding is ISO 8859-1. And the same value would be "Mαrquez" when decoded in ISO 8859-7. The same bytes, different characters. Without knowing the encoding we cannot talk about Unicode characters.

Comment: thanks for the great reply. But what if I wanted to include spaces, '.'s and ','s ?

Answer (score 0):

For Python < 3 you may want to enable locale:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

And then use `re.LOCALE` option with your regexpes:

```
re.findall('\w+', 'Márquez', re.LOCALE)
```

Though, probably Unicode is the better way to go, though it requires decoding the data from and encoding it to your local encoding.